# How to export session fom Fiddler with Java instruction in AfterTestCase Katalon

Tags: java, https, export, fiddler, katalon-studio

I'm looking for a possibilty to export https request from Fiddler with Java in a Test Listener file with Katalon.

With the BeforeTestCase I've succeeded to launch Fiddler, my mobile test with Katalon run, but I don't know how to do in Java to export all session in a specific format.

I'm french and I hope my demand is clear. Moreover, Java is not where I perform to be honest ;)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Code usually makes the demands/expectations clear. Try adding what the short version of the code you've done so far.

Comment: For automated testing from within Java Fiddler is IMHO a bad choice. I would have selected a Java based proxy like [OWASP Zap](https://www.zaproxy.org/) that has similar capabilities or a command-line system like `mitmdump` from mitmproxy.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your answer, I Will take a look !

Comment: @drekbour It's litteraly nothing at this point, only researches without any clues. To simplify, is it possible, with some Java, litteraly to say to Fiddler : "okay now export all sessions here with this configuration" ? Thans for your help BTW :)